# OpenCL Profiling timestamps are not consistent in duration compared to CPU clock

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl

I am creating a custom tool interface with my application to profile the performance of OpenCL kernels while also integrating CPU profiling points. I'm currently working with this code on Linux using Ubuntu, and am testing using the 3 OpenCL devices in my machine: Intel CPU, Intel IGP, and Nvidia Quadro.

I am using this code `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()` to produce a timestamp on the CPU, and of course for the OpenCL profiling time points, they are 64-bit nanoseconds provided from the OpenCL profiling events API. The purpose of the tool I made is to consume log output (specially formatted and generated so as not to impact performance much) from the program and generate a timeline chart to aid performance analysis.

So far in my visualization interface I had made the assumption that nanoseconds are uniform. I've realized now after getting my visual interface working and checking a few assumptions that this condition more or less does hold to a standard deviation of 0.4 microsecond for the CPU OpenCL device (which indicates that the CPU device could be implemented using the same time counter, as it has no drift), but does not hold for the two GPU devices! This is perhaps not the most surprising thing in the world, but it affects the core design of my tool, so this was an unforeseen risk.

I'll provide some eye candy since it is very interesting and it does prove to me that this is indeed happening.

This is zoomed into the beginning of the profile where the GPU has the corresponding mapBuffer for poses happening around a millisecond before the CPU calls it (impossible!)

[image: at the beginning]

Toward the end of the profile we see the same shapes but reversed relationship, clearly showing that GPU seconds seem to count for a little bit less compared to CPU seconds.

[image: near the end]

The way that this visualization currently works as i had assumed a GPU nanosecond is indeed a CPU nanosecond, is that I actually have been computing the average of the delta between the values given to me by the CPU and GPU... Since I did implement this initially, perhaps it indicates that i was at least subconsciously expecting there to be an issue like this one. Anyway, what I did was establish a sync point at the kernel dispatch by recording a CPU timestamp immediately before calling `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` and then comparing this against the `CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED` OpenCL Profile event time. This delta upon further inspection showed the time drift:

[image: console screenshot]

This screenshot from the chrome console shows me logging the array of delta values I collected from these two GPU devices; they are showing BigInts to avoid losing integer precision: in both cases the GPU reported timestamp deltas are trending down.

Compare with the numbers from the CPU:

[image: cpu console screenshot]

My questions:

- What might be a practical way to deal with this issue? I am currently leaning toward the use of sync points when dispatching OpenCL kernels, and these sync points could be used to either locally piecewise stretch the OpenCL Profiling timestamps, or to locally sync at the beginning of, say, a kernel dispatch and just ignore the discrepancy we have, assuming it will be insignificant during the period. In particular it is unclear whether it'd be a good idea to maximize granularity by implementing a sync point for every single profiling event I want to use.
- What might be some other time measuring systems I can or should use on the CPU-side to see if maybe they will end up aligning better? I don't really have much hope in this at this point because I can imagine that the profiling times being provided to me are actually generated and timed on the GPU device itself. The fluctuations would then be affected by such things as dynamic GPU clock scaling, and there would be no hope of stumbling upon a different better timekeeping scheme on the CPU.